# How to use Rest-Assured for testing REST API

Tags: rest, testing, rest-assured

I am new to REST API testing. Is there a guide for beginners on how to test REST APIs?

I will be using Rest-Assured for testing REST APIs. Please guide me from the scratch.

Comment: Hi, did u get a chance to configure rest-assured project and work on it? I have been facing problem to configure rest-assure project itself.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be better to provide a bit more information about (let's say) what language or tool do you plan to use. In any case the answers to your question as it is - will be too broad. Here is something to

> guide me from the scratch

- [Getting Started with RESTful Web Services](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)
- [SoapUI and Rest services](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/09/05/soapui-how-to-test-a-rest-service/)
- [SoapUI getting started](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html)
- [Rest services and jMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
- [JAVA Restful testing](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/java-restful-api-integration-testing.html)

Hope it helps.

UPDATE:

You can use this [rest-assured library](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/29/rest-assured-2-0-testing-your-rest-services-is-easier-than-ever/), since it’s built to scale to simple and more advanced use cases using detailed configuration, filters, specifications etc. Here is [additional tutorial](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/02/07/rest-testing-with-java-getting-started-with-rest-assured/).

Another option is [Java DSL](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) - it brings the simplicity of using Rest. Also [open-source JUnit extension](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/restfuse/).

Comment: Ill be using java. Ill be using rest-assured to test rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Rest-Assured has a getting started section at

- https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted

There is also great instruction on various blogs like

- Part 1 http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/02/07/rest-testing-with-java-getting-started-with-rest-assured/
- Part 2 http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/02/26/rest-testing-with-java-part-two-getting-started-with-rest-assured/

And also

- http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/testing-rest-apis-with-rest-assured.html